# How do i sort month and year in pandas for timeseries visualization?

Tags: pandas, sorting, plot, group-by, time-series

```
#plot data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(25,17))

plt.ylabel('No of tweets', fontsize=12)
#plt.xlim([1,20])
plt.title('Number of tweets', fontsize = 20)
data.sort_values(by = ['Year','Month'], ascending=[True,True]).groupby(['Month','Year']).count()['text'].plot(ax=ax)
plt.xlabel('Month-Year', fontsize=12)
```

[I have attached the current output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keMpv.png)

Can you help me understand what I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Combine `Year` and `Month` columns to a new column `Date`

```
data['Date'] = data['Year'].astype('str') + '-' \
               + data['Month'].astype('str').str.zfill(2)

# Groupby sort groups by default
data.groupby('Date')['text'].count().plot(ax=ax)
```